# (VBA) Show random worksheet on EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have 5 sheets open on 1 excel file, named as `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4`, `Sheet5`. As I want a button on `Sheet1`, when I press that button just say as `Show Me`. That button will randomly show me one of 4 sheets remaining of my file (`Sheet2` to `Sheet5`).

How can I achieve this task?  I did some research on Google and couldn’t find out solution.

Comment: `I did some research on Google and couldn’t find out solution.` What keywords did you use to search in Google?

Answer (score 3):

I was not planning on posting an answer but since, there is already an answer posted. Here is my version.

**Logic**:

1. Create a function which returns a random number between 2 numbers
2. Use that number to set your worksheet and then activate it

**Code**:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(RandomNumber(5, 2))
    ws.Activate

LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Public Function RandomNumber(ByVal MaxValue As Long, _
ByVal MinValue As Long) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Randomize Timer
    RandomNumber = Int((MaxValue - MinValue + 1) * Rnd) + MinValue
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign this macro to your button:

```
Sub PickRandomSheet()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Sheets("Sheet" & wf.RandBetween(2, 5)).Activate
End Sub
```